# verify if the Ground cable is connected to Neutral cable

Tags: receptacle, grounding, neutral

I want to verify if electricity outlet is grounded. For this I did a test using a bulb connecting it to Phase and Neutral and it lit (to verify if bulb works). Then connected with Phase and Ground and the bulb lit up again. As I still doubted it, I found out where the grounding rod is installed and removed the cable connecting it to the mains (at the grounding rod). Then did the same test and found out that the bulb still lights up. My understanding on this is ... either there is another grounding point or the Neutral is connected to the Ground plug point. Am I correct? How can I verify if the Ground cable is connected to Neutral cable? Thanks

Comment: If you're in the USA, ground and neutral are usually bonded together in the breaker panel.

Comment: The second experiment should have tripped an RCD (GFCI) somewhere, if your protection systems are reasonably up to date.

Comment: @ThePhoton I have no idea what definition of electrical engineer you are using, but if you think electrical supply is not engineering and electricians are not engineers, and that they are under "home improvement", you have a rather woefully poor understanding of, um, electrical engineering.

Comment: @IanBland, In the US, electricians are definitely not engineers. Electricians follow rules (code). Engineers make the rules.

Comment: @IanBland, also, much like ee.se is not strictly limited to electrical engineering (for example, we occassionally answer questions about optics or manufacturing), diy.se is not strictly limited to questions about home improvement.

Comment: @ThePhoton You'll find that both do both, when you get off your high horse. Additionally, I'd be a little surprised if the average questioner here switching LEDs on and off with an Arduino is "making the rules". Furthermore, you might want to ponder that most of the serious electrician work is not going on in homes. I find it amusing to consider that somebody with advanced expertise dealing with thousands of amps and volts is not engineering, but somebody with a 9V battery and a few components on a breadboard apparently is.

Comment: Electricians know lots of things I don't. Like what rating of conduit to use for direct burial, etc. Technicians at my office know lots of things I don't, like how to assemble a BNC coaxial connector that won't come apart. Bakers know lots of things I don't, like how to make choux pastry. That doesn't make them engineers. Heck, in many jurisdictions, I couldn't be called an engineer because I don't have a PE. It's not a high horse. It's a recognition that different jobs require different knowledge.

Comment: @IanBland, if you hire an electrician and they're making new rules without a sign-off by a licensed engineer, that's not going to work out well when the inspector shows up.

Comment: @IanBland, and no, making LEDs blink with an Arduino is not engineering either. But more experts on residential electrical installations answer questions on diy.se than here, so that is a better place for this question.

Comment: Here in the UK electricians sign our own work off, perhaps because we're properly trained or something. More to the point, I still fail to see why electrics isn't "electrical engineering", especially as so far as I know most of the punters here aren't getting their Arduino mash-ups signed off by Chartered Engineers. If the site were called "Electronic Engineering", you might have a point. But it isn't. And I repeat that designating all of electrics as "home improvement" is very odd.

Comment: @IanBland, because most of the people answering questions here, if they know how ground and neutral are bonded in a residential install, know it from DIY work, not from professional work. If the question is moved to DIY there will be several professional electricians who will have the opportunity to read it and answer it properly, from their professional knowledge. Yes there are power specialists in electrical engineering. We've had a few contribute here. As far as I know, none of them are currently active on this site.

Comment: Get an electrician! You don't know what you are doing and when removing the ground rod bond you set up a potentially hazardous condition. In my state a supervising electrician has the same ability to design, layout, and install complete electrical systems.

Answer (score 3):

In Canada (and probably US) the Neutral and house Ground are connected in the main breaker panel, and that point is connected to a earth ground rod nearby.  The power company also connects the Neutral to an earth ground at each distribution transformer.  The specifics of Earth ground and Neutral/Ground connections may vary in different jurisdictions.

Comment: In the U.S. a transformer vault is (in many cases , states, counties) required to have 2 ground rods and copper wire connecting them.+@ Peter Bennett,  This is seperate from the home's grounding rod / Ufer ground that are bonded to the neutral & ground buds in the main panel only.

Answer (score 3):

Further to what Peter Bennett says above, here in the UK the two main systems are TNS and TNCS as we call them. TNS is a system in which Earth and Neutral are supplied to the consumer via separate conductors, whereas in TNCS they are combined as one conductor as far as the consumer unit and then separate after it. So it depends what you have. The Earthing rod in your installation is probably there not as the Earth path, but to, er, Earth the earth, which ensures that the local Earth (literally, the earth) is at the same potential as the common Earth of the electrical distribution system.

So it's unlikely that disconnecting the Earth rod will disconnect your Earth from the Neutral, since they are connected either at the incoming service head or at the supply company's transformer.

Answer (score 0):

@d_esTin_y

It is common to see ***improper residential upgrades*** even in advanced urban areas like Toronto.  done improperly, by  immigrant trades people with no professional training, just trying to make a living.

In my previous home the previous owners had contractors upgrade the house with 50 ceiling pot-lights on all floors and when I went to add a 2 way stair/hallway switch, I found they mis-wired it and I had bulb current glowing thru the safety ground in the attic and in wall switch.

You are doing a good test but trace it back to the breaker panel and check earth water mains copper for a ground reference with a Voltmeter.

There is an allowance of 5% of Vac for line voltage on neutral from conduction loss  and ground resistance can be as high as 100 Ohms or so at the pole in dry areas in dry weather.

Check your breaker panel to sub-ground water plumbing then check

- L1 to N
- L2 to N then
- N to Gnd in different places with load ON.

A $10 DMM is a good investment if you don't have one.